# QML window minimal size with frame

Tags: qt, qml

I want to set minimal size for my QML window. But if I set the minimal width and height inside my main.qml I've got the window that has minimal size bigger than I set & expect. 
The problem is that the minimal size is applied to the view inside window frame and the window frame and caption size is not taken into account.

```js
ApplicationWindow {
  id: application
  minimumWidth: 1024
  minimumHeight: 768
  visibility: "Maximized"
}
```

Is there a way to set application window minimal size taking into account window frame?

I use Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @luke_carter already said, it's possible by calling one of QFrame's function related to its size, for example [QFrame::frameGeometry()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#frameRect-prop).It gets you window size **including** frame and titlebar. So all you need is to ajust the QML window size. I think the best way to do that with a singleton with suitable functions, for example:

```
QRect MySingleton::frameSize(QObject *window)
{
    QQuickWindow *qw = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(window);
    if(qw)
        return qw->frameGeometry();
    return QRect();
}
```

In QML:

```
Window {
    id: wnd
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var rect = MySingleton.frameSize(wnd);
        console.log(rect.width + "," + rect.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe hide the frame using `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` (or `-frameless` if using qml viewer)? I'm guessing it's because the frame is part of the windowing system of the OS.

Just found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/9496/setting-window-size-including-window-frame), may be possible to get the frame size from the target OS.